# attempted to read or write protected memory c# and c++

Tags: c#, c++, memory, dll, export

Let me first explain what I'm building so it will help you understand how to fix my problem .
I built dll file that is injected to program, then with a function that is inside the dll,
its editing a memory address inside the program, but this function is exported to my c# app .

when I'm calling the function from c#, I'm getting this error: attempted to read or write protected memory .

my dll code (c++):

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void GamePool_Vehicle_GetAt()
{
    DWORD d;
    VirtualProtect((PVOID)0x863984,4,PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE,&d);
    *(float*)0x863984 = 0.0008f;
}
```

the import function in c#:

```
[DllImport(@"C:\Users\ABCD\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\uclient_dll2\Debug\uclient_dll2.dll", EntryPoint = "GamePool_Vehicle_GetAt",
CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern void GamePool_Vehicle_GetAt();
```

the usage in c#:

```
private void button3_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GamePool_Vehicle_GetAt();
}
```

I will appreciate any help .

Comment: Is the memory in question by any chance mapping the executable? If so, `VirtualProtect` will have returned `0` (failure), and `GetLastError()` would be set...

Comment: GetLastError() returning 87

Comment: MSDN says: ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER. First result for "windows getlasterror 87"

Comment: You have any clue how to solve it ?